# How T Get Specific Column From a Specific Row In PHP/MySql

Tags: php, mysql

How T Get Specific Column From a Specific Row In PHP/MySql
I got a table "users" and I have to fetch column "profile" from row where name = $Name
CAn anyone help me?

Comment: And your `query` is? If you have `query` related question then you should add tag for `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Select profile from users where name ='".$Name."'";
```

This query will fetch profile from users where the name will exact match with $Name. If you want to perform like query use this

```
"Select profile from users where name like '%".$Name."%'";
```

Comment: But beware of sql injection

Comment: Yes definetly @Strawberry this is just a quick idea for OP. :)